# How do I stop embedded sound clips from being downloaded to the browser cache before they are requested to be played?

Tags: php, html, audio, preloading

I have been scratching my head with this one for a few days,

I am building a web app for a client associated with call tracking. One aspect of the system is to allow for short recorded voicemail messages to be played directly from a "play" button beside the message details.

I am accessing the sound files as such;

```
$wavefile=$calls_row['recording'];
if (file_exists("/var/spool/asterisk/monitor/".$calls_row['recording'].".wav")){
    $wavefile="
          <form>
              <input type=\"button\" value=\"Play\" onClick=\"PlaySound('clip-".$stat_id."')\" />
          </form>
          <embed src=\"pass-thru.php?f=".$calls_row['recording'].".wav\" autostart=\"false\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\" id=\"clip-".$stat_id."\" enablejavascript=\"true\" />
        ";
}
```

The sound clips are stored outside the web root in a directory I have been told we cannot change. Being unable to get at the files locally I put together a small php pass-through script to pass me the file back to my web page.

The sound clip is using a small piece of javascript to get the ID of the link for the specified file before playing it;

```
function PlaySound(soundobj) {
  var thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
  thissound.Play();
}
```

The files are accessed outside the webroot and passed to the html by the following php code;

```
$basedir = '/var/spool/asterisk/monitor';
$clip = $_GET['f'];
$file = $basedir.'/'.$clip;
$ext = array_pop(explode ('.', $file));
if(file_exists($file) && $ext != '' && isset($allowed[strToLower($ext)])) {
    $type = $allowed[strToLower($ext)];
}
header("Content-type: audio/x-wav");
header("Content-Disposition: filename='{$file}'");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit();
```

Everything works fine as it should, the clips are passed through and the sound clips play in the browser.

The problem is that all of the soundclips are loaded into the cache when the page loads, obviously slowing things down a bit. I have the results paginated so its only downloading 25 at a time but I would really love to just have the links to the soundclips available and that they are only downloaded when selected to be played.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option I can think of is not embedding the sound file in the HTML. As far as I know, the old-school `embed` element has no options to turn off preloading of sound files, for this feature you should look into HTML5's `audio` (which is not working in old IEs of course).

So basically, you just don't put an `embed` element into your HTML code, and when the Play button is clicked, you insert the `embed` element from Javascript. The data you need for the `embed` element to be created (URL for example) can be stored in a `data-` attribute, or in your case, simply written to the inline event handler's parameter list.

If you need to care about users with Javascript turned off, you can still include the `embed` element in a `noscript` tag (hopefully it won't start preloading).

For this method you only need some basic functions like [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) and [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/InsertBefore).

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna go down the html5 audio route initially but they have 50% + vsistors using IE7 and IE8, so its not an option. Your idea about using the DOM to insert the embed element might actually work, I'll give that a try.